# Creating a python class with ONLY read-only instance attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, properties, readonly

When developing code for test automation, I often transform responses from the SUT from XML / JSON / whatever to a Python object model to make working with it afterwards easier.

Since the client should not alter the information stored in the object model, it would make sense to have all instance attributes read-only.

For simple cases, this can be achieved by using a namedtuple from the collections module. But in most cases, a simple namedtuple won't do.

I know that the probably most pythonic way would be to use properties:

```
class MyReadOnlyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.__a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.__a
```

This is OK if I'm dealing only with a few attributes, but it gets lengthy pretty soon.

So I was wondering if there would be any other acceptable approach? What I came up with was this:

```
MODE_RO = "ro"
MODE_RW = "rw"
class ReadOnlyBaseClass(object):
    __mode = MODE_RW

    def __init__(self):
        self.__mode = MODE_RO

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if self.__mode != MODE_RW:
            raise AttributeError("May not set attribute")
        else:
            self.__dict__[key] = value
```

I could then subclass it and use it like this:

```
class MyObjectModel(ReadOnlyBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        super(MyObjectModel, self).__init__()
```

After the super call, adding or modifying instance attributes is not possible (... that easily, at least).

A possible caveat I came to think about is that if someone was to modify the __mode attribute and set it to MODE_RO, no new instances could be created. But that seems acceptable since its clearly marked as "private" (in the Pyhon way).

I would be interested if you see any more problems with this solution, or have completely different and better approaches. 
Or maybe discourage this at all (with explanation, please)?

Comment: This is an interesting question and I got a solution of my own already but I'd like to see others posting theirs first. Btw, you're aware there isn't the concept of private stuff on python, right? for instance, those `self.__whateverattribute` are mangled... So they more like "pseudo-private" attributes. I think a better solution than having a readonly-class would be having readonly/writable attributes... Which would be a more general solution to the problem

Comment: Honestly, this looks like a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). An answer to your question would be just "That's a good solution", and I don't think that's the kind of answer we want to have on SO.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Well, while it makes sense what you're saying there, it's sad... cos moving interesting questions like this one to a less-trafic site like codereview will produce a less ammount of interesting answers. IMHO Code-Review is just a little subset of SO, domain intersection of those sites is quite diffuse sometimes. Cos here in SO you'll see a lot of refactoring questions where working code has been posted

Comment: [https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Aran-Frey you are right, I actually thought about posting it there. But my main intent was not for SO to review my solution, but to hint out reasons why this approach was too "simple" and maybe would become problematic in situations where I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: @BPL I am looking forward to see your solution. Yes I am aware of the "pseudo-private" nature, that's what I meant with "(in the Python way)".